# Matlab object instance update

Tags: matlab, object, struct

## Problem description

I'm trying to construct an object of the class **Analysis** with a variable amount of subclasses **Resset** stored as a structure in the Analysis property *ressets* (see Matlab code below). The classdef **Analysis** has a method called *addResset* that constructs a new instance of **Resset** and sets this instance to the property *ressets*. However, when I create an instance, let's say A, of the class Analysis and I add a Resset object using A.addResset the method does not automatically update the property ressets in instance A:

```
>> A = Analysis('some_name');

>> A.addResset('some_res');

>> A

 A =

 Properties: 
     name: 'some_name'
  ressets: []
stepTypes: []

 Methods

Analysis     addResset
```

Instead I have to write:

```
>> A = A.addResset('some_res')  

Properties:
     name: 'some_name'
  ressets: [1x1 struct]
stepTypes: []
```

Why does Matlab not update the instance *A* when I call *A* with its method? As long as the Analysis class is '*flat*', this is not a big issue. However, in my (actual) case every Resset class will have Data classes as well (i.e. another nested level). Currently, I generate an empty instance of Analysis, add some Resset classes, add Data classes to each individual Resset class and afterward I have to update every parent object up to the top level (i.e. Analysis). It's making my script excessively long and messy.

I am relatively new to the object oriented programming part of Matlab. Did I do something wrong in the definition of my addResset method? In python an instance seems to be updated automatically when referenced in a method, I would expect that Matlab had similar functionality?

## Matlab code

Matlab version: 7.13.0.564 (R2011b 32bits)

```
classdef Analysis

properties
    name
    ressets          %structure of Resset objects
    stepTypes
end

methods 
    function obj = Analysis(name)
        % ANALYSIS contructs an analysis object
        if nargin > 0
            obj.name = name;
        end
    end
end
 
methods
    function [obj resset valid_fieldname] = addResset(obj,name)
        %create a new Resset class instance(PackageName.ClassName)
        resset = xrf_read.Resset(name);
        %replace 'possible' dots in name (=invalid fieldname)
        valid_fieldname = regexprep(name,'\.','_');
        %add Resset instance to ressets property
        obj.ressets.(valid_fieldname) = resset;
    end
end

end
```

For the sake of simplicity the Resset class looks like

```
classdef Resset

properties
    name
    datas
end

methods
    function obj = Resset(name)
        % RESSET constructs a resset object
        if nargin > 0
            obj.name = name;
        end
    end
end

end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short: make your classes subclass of handle.

These old style classes follow the "copy on write" principle meaning they will not change the original instance.

Comment: +1, though I wouldn't call these 'old style' classes - value classes are actually the correct choice in certain situations. See [here](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/matlab_oop/comparing-handle-and-value-classes.html) and [here](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/matlab_oop/which-kind-of-class-to-use.html).

Comment: Sweet, I got it working the way I want. It seems I didn't understood the difference between the Matlab Value and Handle classes... Thanks!

Comment: to the "old style" I was refering that this class style was available *before* the handele classes. I also think I read that the *handle* behavior will become standard in some time.